# How to install and configure Apache Toree for Jupyter notebook in windows 10?

Tags: apache-spark, windows-10, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

Can some one help me with the installation and configuration of apache toree for jupyter notebook in Windows 10? I tried it but was unsuccessful.
Error encountered is as follows.

Failed to start Kernel

Unknown server error.

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 75, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 307, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 94, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 243, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 189, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 123, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: It would help if you described what you tried and why it didn't work, or what error messages you got.

Comment: tried installing apache toree as a kernel in jupyter for running spark application.

Comment: I would like to expand my issue in more detail.Initially in Windows 10 i installed anaconda latest version and then launched jupyter. By default Python3 kernel was available but as i was supposed to work with Spark i installed and configured Apache Toree for pyspark, SQL, Scala. All the newly added kernel are shown in jupyter kernelspec list but when i open the newly added kernels in jupyter it shows kernel error which states "Failed to start kernel" looking to the already available stackoverflow answers i also tried to change the path in kernel.json file but it also did not work. Please help.

Comment: how did you install spark? I think the problem is with your spark installation and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Toree uses `%PROG_HOME%\bin\run.sh` to start the kernel.

Usually `PROG_HOME` is `C:\Users\{Account_Name}\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\apache_toree_scala` on Windows.

Since Windows cannot run shell script, it throws OS error:

> [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

You need to follow below steps:

1. Download Spark version compatible with Scala 2.11 and set SPARK_HOME environment variable. Note that Apache Toree kernel version 0.3.0-incubating uses Scala version 2.11.
2. Create a Windows batch file (*run.bat*) or Windows Command script file (*run.cmd*) at `%PROG_HOME%/bin`. Similar to *run.sh*, use below command to start the kernel through `SparkSubmit.scala` class.

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -cp "%SPARK_HOME%\jars\*;%PROG_HOME%\lib\toree-assembly-0.3.0-incubating.jar;." -Dscala.usejavacp=true org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit %SPARK_OPTS% --class org.apache.toree.Main %PROG_HOME%\lib\toree-assembly-0.3.0-incubating.jar %TOREE_OPTS% %*
```

3. Update the `argv` parameter value in *kernel.json* file in `PROG_HOME` folder from *run.sh* to *run.cmd*
4. Start Anaconda Prompt. Run `jupyter notebook` command. Select "Apache Toree - Scala" kernel from browser. You can see kernel connection status on Anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

would like to add to @UmeshD's answer above
If you are using toree-assembly-0.3.0-incubating, create a file run.cmd (in `C:\Users\{Account_Name}\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\apache_toree_scala/bin/`) and paste the following code below

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0\..\"
set PROG_HOME=%cd%
popd

if not defined SPARK_HOME ( 
    echo "SPARK_HOME must be set to the location of a Spark distribution!"
    Exit /b
)

echo "Starting Spark Kernel with SPARK_HOME=%SPARK_HOME%"


rem for /f %%i in ('dir /B toree-assembly-*.jar') do set KERNEL_ASSEMBLY=%%i popd

rem disable randomized hash for string in Python 3.3+
set PYTHONHASHSEED=0
rem set TOREE_ASSEMBLY=%PROG_HOME%/lib/%KERNEL_ASSEMBLY%
rem The SPARK_OPTS values during installation are stored in __TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__. This allows values to be specified during
rem install, but also during runtime. The runtime options take precedence over the install options.
if not defined SPARK_OPTS (
    if defined __TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__ (
        set SPARK_OPTS=%__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__%
    )
)

if not defined TOREE_OPTS (
    if defined __TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__ (
        set TOREE_OPTS=%__TOREE_OPTS__%
    )
)

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -cp "%SPARK_HOME%\jars\*;%PROG_HOME%\lib\toree-assembly-0.3.0-incubating.jar;." -Dscala.usejavacp=true org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit %SPARK_OPTS% --class org.apache.toree.Main %PROG_HOME%\lib\toree-assembly-0.3.0-incubating.jar %TOREE_OPTS% %*
```